# Remove all elements in QJsonArray

Tags: c++, qt

I want to remove all the elements from a QJsonArray and I am experiencing way more troubles than I thought. Here is my code:

```
void Assessment::clearQJsonArray(QJsonArray *array) {
  printQJsonArray(*array);
  for(int i=0;i<array->count();i++) {
      array->removeAt(i);
  }

  qDebug() << "Test clear:" << array->count();

  printQJsonArray(*array);
}

void Assessment::printQJsonArray(QJsonArray array) {
  QJsonDocument doc;
  doc.setArray(array);
  qDebug() << doc.toJson();
}

void Assessment::testClearQJsonArray() {
QJsonArray array;
QJsonObject obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4;

obj1.insert("number",1);
obj2.insert("number",2);
obj3.insert("number",3);
obj4.insert("number",4);

array.append(obj1);
array.append(obj2);
array.append(obj3);
array.append(obj4);

qDebug() << "Before clear";
qDebug() << "Test size:" << array.count();

QJsonObject element;

for(int i=0;i<array.count();i++) {
    element = array.at(i).toObject();
    qDebug() << element.value("number").toInt();
}

clearQJsonArray(&array);
qDebug() << "After clear";

for(int i=0;i<array.count();i++) {
    element = array.at(i).toObject();
    qDebug() << element.value("number").toInt();
}
qDebug() << "Test size:" << array.count();
}
```

And I'm getting this output:

```
(void Assessment::testClearQJsonArray()): Before clear
(void Assessment::testClearQJsonArray()): Test size: 4
(void Assessment::testClearQJsonArray()): 1
(void Assessment::testClearQJsonArray()): 2
(void Assessment::testClearQJsonArray()): 3
(void Assessment::testClearQJsonArray()): 4
(void Assessment::printQJsonArray(QJsonArray)): "[\n    {\n        \"number\": 1\n    },\n    {\n        \"number\": 2\n    },\n    {\n        \"number\": 3\n    },\n    {\n        \"number\": 4\n    }\n]\n"
(void Assessment::clearQJsonArray(QJsonArray*)): Test clear: 2
(void Assessment::printQJsonArray(QJsonArray)): "[\n    {\n        \"number\": 2\n    },\n    {\n        \"number\": 4\n    }\n]\n"
(void Assessment::testClearQJsonArray()): After clear
(void Assessment::testClearQJsonArray()): 2
(void Assessment::testClearQJsonArray()): 4
(void Assessment::testClearQJsonArray()): Test size: 2
```

I really don't understand why object 1 and 3 are removed, but not 2 and 4. Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code:

```
for(int i=0;i<array->count();i++) {
    array->removeAt(i);
}
```

You do it wrong here. It should be:

```
 for(int i=0; i<array->count(); i++) {
     array->removeAt(0);
 }
```

or

```
 while(array->count()) {
     array->pop_back();
 }
```

Just think what your cycle does: it removes first element at 0 index. Immidiately after `removeAt` call your array is reduced and shifted on one step left. 1st index becomes 0, 2nd becomes 1st and so on. So, on a next iteration, when your `i` becomes 1, it actually points on a former 2. So you'll remove 1st and 3rd elements and 2nd and 4th will be skipped by i++.

That's how your deletion looks like (^ is an `i` pointer):

```
|0|1|2|3|
 ^

|1|2|3|
   ^

|1|3|
     ^
```

Comment: How about `*array = QJsonArray{};`?

Comment: @nwp Yes, that definitely should work. The point is that the question actually is not about `QJsonArray` but related to any container like this. And programmer should understand _why_ code like above is incorrect to avoid such mistakes in a future. It is strange that `QJsonArray` does not have something like `clear()`, so your variant is the shortest for this case.

Comment: @nwp but isn't it going to cause memory leaks ?

Comment: @highvoltage379 It shouldn't. If it does report it as a bug.

Answer (score 2):

If you have using of `pointer` :

```
*array = QJsonArray();
```

And, if you have a simple object of `QJsonArray` :

```
array = QJsonArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The while loop in the answer is correct, but both for loops are wrong.  The problem is that you're loop is incrementing i each time through the loop and the array->count() decrements each time through the loop. This causes them to meet in the middle so you only delete half of the elements in the array.  To fix this you could use a variable.

```
 int len=array->count();
 for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
     array->removeAt(0);
 }
```

Or better yet, just use the while loop.