# list.remove method doesn't work properly

Tags: python, list

I have the next piece of code which counts unique elements in list and remove those elements from that list:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in l:
    if l.count(i) == 1:
        l.remove(i)
print l
```

However, after list modification by l.remove(i) I still have elements in the list: [2, 4]

My question is why list.remove() operation doesn't delete all elements if all of them are unique and amount per each one will be 1 during each iteration?

Comment: how about proper code formatting?

Comment: Already corrected

Comment: You have to look into "deleting from list in loop" like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating).

Comment: here I explained why such kind of things happen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45032978/remove-all-elements-in-qjsonarray/45033170#45033170

Comment: @NikolaiShalakin, great thank you! Absolutely clear now!